# Error while creating a virtual environment with python3.9 in a MacBook Pro M2 Pro

Tags: python, macos

I am on a MacBook Pro M2 Pro. I am trying to create a virtual environment for my project.

> pip3 --version
> pip 23.2.1 from /Users/path/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

> which python3 --> /usr/bin/python3

> which pip3 --> /usr/bin/pip3

When I try to create a virtual environment I get,
`python3 -m venv vMyEnv Error: Command '['/Users/usename/path/to/project/vMyEnv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Is it a problem with my python installation. Recently I have installed react and Xcode and then I have uninstalled.

Now my pip3 list looks like below,

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
altgraph   0.17.2
future     0.18.2
macholib   1.15.2
pip        23.2.1
setuptools 58.0.4
six        1.15.0
wheel      0.37.0
```

Am I missing out something,

Comment: How did you install python? Is there a specific reason not to use latest 3.11?

Comment: you need to install python-venv, just do `python3 -m pip install venv` first and then go ahead with venv

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am a new Mac user. I just saw that my MacBook contains python3 and I started using it. Suddenly not sure if I deleted any file, it's not working now.

Comment: It's not recommended to use system python, or install extra packages into it. You can use pyenv or conda to manage other, newer version installations